# Get data from flutter in Native code without FlutterViewController

Tags: flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I have both iOS and Android native projects and now I am developing a flutter module that can be accessed from both of the platforms. I followed documentation [here for adding flutter to existing application](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps).

I have used method channel for communication between native and flutter components. Now I want to get some data from flutter component in native part. What I am doing is creating method channel with flutter engine as the binary messenger.

```
    let flutterEngine = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).flutterEngine!
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "my.channel.name"
                                       binaryMessenger: flutterEngine)
    channel.invokeMethod("get_value", arguments: nil) { (value) in
        guard let string = value as? String else { return }
        self.valueLabel.text = "value received : " + string
    }
```

And in flutter

```
class CommunicationChannel {
  static const channel = MethodChannel("my.channel.name");

  void startListening() {
    print(" startListening........... ");

    channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
      print("channel method " + call.method);
      switch (call.method) {

        case 'get_value':

          return myValue
        default:
          throw MissingPluginException();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`main()` function

```
void main() {
  print(" main() ------------------------. ");

  CommunicationChannel channel = CommunicationChannel();
  channel.startListening();

  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

My concern is, even though I am not present any view here, a widget is created in main function which is unused.
Is there any way to read values from flutter in native code without creating any view/widget?

Comment: do you want a platform channel? https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels
Add2App is meant to integrate native views into flutter. It is just much easier to grab raw data overall

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am using method channel itself currently. I am looking for a solution to communicate b/w flutter and native code without any widget created.